# downloading multiple images with ParseFile using ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist, imageview, parse-server

I am unable to store image bitmap in global arraylist. I have declared a global arraylist
final ArrayList prod_image =  new ArrayList();
I am trying to call images from Parse Server and save it in the array list.
In ParseFile callback, I am trying to save the bitmap ,
 prod_image.add(bp);
However, the array is returning a null value outside the callback.

How can I store an the images in array in callback?

```
ParseFile file = (ParseFile) object.get("image_book");

                            file.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                                    if(e== null && data != null){

                                       Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);

                                       if(bitmap != null){
                                           Log.i("image download","Success");

                                           bp = bitmap;
                                           Log.i("image Content",bp.toString());

                                           prod_image.add(bp);
                                           //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                           if(prod_image.size()>0){
                                               Log.i("inside count","Ok");
                                           }else {
                                               Log.i("inside Count","Not Ok");
                                           }


                                           //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                                       }else {
                                           Log.i("image download","Failure");
                                       }
                                    }else {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            });


`
public class UserFeed extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView account;
    ImageView notif;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    //UserFeedAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<String> prod_name ;
    ArrayList<String> prod_cat;
    ArrayList<String> prod_pub;
    ArrayList<String> prod_price;

    Bitmap bp=null;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    final ArrayList<Bitmap> prod_image =  new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
    //final Bitmap bitmap;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_feed);
        //setTitle("My Feed");

        account = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.account);
        notif = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.notif);

        account.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AccountActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        notif.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NotificationActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        //myListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);


        prod_name = new ArrayList<>();
        prod_cat = new ArrayList<>();
        prod_pub = new ArrayList<>();
        prod_price = new ArrayList<>();


        //MyData myImage = new MyData();

        ParseQuery<ParseObject> dashboardQuery = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Sell");
        dashboardQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
                if(e == null){
                    if(objects.size() > 0){
                        for (final ParseObject object : objects){
                            String name = (String) object.get("name");
                            String cat = (String) object.get("category");
                            String pub = (String)object.get("publisher");
                            String price = (String) object.get("price");
                            //Bitmap image = (Bitmap)object.get("image_book");

                            prod_name.add(name);
                            prod_cat.add(cat);
                            prod_pub.add(pub);
                            prod_price.add(price);


                            //prod_image.add(image);

                            ParseFile file = (ParseFile) object.get("image_book");

                            file.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                                    if(e== null && data != null){

                                       Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);

                                       if(bitmap != null){
                                           Log.i("image download","Success");

                                           bp = bitmap;
                                           Log.i("image Content",bp.toString());

                                           prod_image.add(bp);
                                           //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                           if(prod_image.size()>0){
                                               Log.i("inside count","Ok");
                                           }else {
                                               Log.i("inside Count","Not Ok");
                                           }


                                           //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                                       }else {
                                           Log.i("image download","Failure");
                                       }
                                    }else {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            });

                            //prod_image.add(bp);
                            //<-- not ok
                          //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        }

                    }
                }
                if(prod_image.size()>0){
                    Log.i("outside count","Ok");
                }else {
                    Log.i("outside Count","Not Ok");
                }
                //<-- It's first crashing then second time its loading successfully!!
                adapter = new UserFeedAdapter(prod_name,prod_cat,prod_pub,prod_price,prod_image);
                //recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });


        //<---Not working at all
        //adapter = new UserFeedAdapter(prod_name,prod_cat,prod_pub,prod_price,prod_image);
       //recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        if(prod_image.size()>0){
            Log.i("very outside count","Ok");
        }else {
            Log.i("very outside Count","Not Ok");
        }


    }




    }`
```

Comment: If this is your actual code, and not just a (very long) simplifiction: your array is being filled up asynchronously, so checking its content directly after calling `findInBackground` cannot work. Instead you should call a callback in your download handler when all files have been fetched, and perform your next actions there.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare the Array as global, then, after adding the bitmap in your bitmap-array, you have to update the adapter and it should work. But, be careful because it takes time to do that and should be done in ASYNC, especially if the images are big and heavy.

```
public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
if(e== null && data != null){
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
if(bitmap != null){
Log.i("image download","Success");
bp = bitmap;
Log.i("image Content",bp.toString());
prod_image.add(bp);  
//----------------- UPDATE YOUR ARRAY-ADAPTER HERE-----------------
yourView.setAdapter(prod_image);
enter code here
```

Comment: what do you mean with "global"? Could you add a code sample?

Comment: the variables/arrays can be either global (if they are declared on the top of the main activity method) or local (if they are declared within a "no-main" method). The problem with the code above is that is using a local variable to fill in a global array.

Comment: the bitmap is copied into bp which is declared "global" by your definition (I would call it a member or attribute of the class)